# What is the best way to redirect 57,000 URLs on nginx?

Tags: nginx, performance, redirect

I'm planning to do a lot of redirects in nginx with mapping files like in the example below, but just discovered that I have to redirect about 57,000 URLs. Is putting them in config files like this the best way to do it, or is there a better way?

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
    /old-path-1     /new-path-1;
    /old-path-2     /new-path-2;
    /old-path-3     /new-path-3;
}
```

The redirects are mostly for the search engines. After they re-index the site, I think there won't be a huge number of hits on the old URLs. I'm mainly concerned about potential problems from creating a configuration file that has that many lines in it.

Update: it worked fine.

Comment: Stating the version you're using might help.

Comment: I'm going to build a new server, so I could use any version. The current server is running 1.10 though.

Comment: Create one with 10 times your desired entries and compare startup time, latency & memory. Will the list grow in the future?

Comment: They are just the URLs from a previous version of the site. The list won't grow significantly in the future, unless there is another rebuild, which would be years away.

Comment: Hi @R891 hope you doing well,  Just want to know if you implemented the solution and how did it go?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki It worked fine with a few thousand visitors per day on a small server.

Answer (score 2):

That should work fine. 
Note you can also use **[include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)** directive for your maps so your config files would look pretty

BTW here are a couple of alternatives:

1. You could also use **proxy_cache** and generate this URLs via PHP/Python/whatever else is behind nginx if it's more convenient for some reason. Note it's much slower
2. Use exact matches, check out this [thread](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,248659,248659#msg-248659)